# How to send form data in React js

Tags: reactjs

I have created small Reactjs application, I want to send data  inside table of form data. how do i send data json format my form data could you please change my code and I refer more website could not solve this and if have reference could you please send me, please change my code.

below my code here

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import FloatingLabel from "react-bootstrap/FloatingLabel";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import { useForm, FormProvider, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import { AES, enc } from 'crypto-js';
import Header from '../Header' 
import Footer from '../Footer' 
import $ from 'jquery';
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams , useLocation } from "react-router-dom"; 
import { decryptedAccessToken, encryptedAccessToken } from "../../Token";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

function HBA() {
  
  const body=$(window).height()
  const header=$("#header").height()
  const nav=$(".navbar").height()
  const footer=$(".footer").height()
  const total_height=header+nav+footer;
  const window_height=body-total_height;
  console.log(total_height)
  console.log(body)
    const location=useLocation();
  const {pricebookName}=location.state;
  console.log(pricebookName)
   
      
  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
   
    fetchData();
  }, [decryptedAccessToken]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://rwood.znapay.in:5000/get/all_hba/'+pricebookName, { 
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedAccessToken}` },        }
      );
      const data = response.data.records;     
      setDatas(data);   
      console.log(data)     
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };
  const { register, handleSubmit,control, reset, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data, e) =>{ 
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(data)
  }
  return (

    <div className="addAccount">
    <Header/>
    <div className="page-header" id='add-account'>
    <div>
      <h2 className="main-content-title tx-24 mg-b-5">Pricebook HBA</h2>
      <ol className="breadcrumb"> 
        <li className="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Dashboard / Pricebook HBA </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <div className="d-flex">
      <div className="justify-content-center">
      
        {/* <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary my-2 btn-icon-text">
         <a href='/account/add-account'> <i className="fe fe-download-cloud me-2"></i><FaPlus/> Add Account</a>
        </button> */}
        
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
    <Form>
    <p className="edit-btn">
                  <button className="btn btn-primary">
                    Save
                  </button>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                     
                  >
                    Cancel
                  </button>
                </p>
                
            
        <table className="table table-bordered hba">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th colSpan='2'> </th>
                <th>Daily</th>
                <th>Daily</th>
                <th>Weekly</th>
                <th>Weekly</th>
                <th>Weekly</th>
                <th>Weekly</th>
                <th>Weekly</th>
                <th>Weekly</th>
                <th>Weekly</th>
                <th>Weekly</th>
                <th>Current Month</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Remakrs</th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Day</th>
                <th>Platts K5900</th>
                <th>GCNEW 6322  </th>
                <th>NEX</th>
                <th>ICI1 6500</th>
                <th>ICI2 5800</th>
                <th>ICI3 5000</th>
                <th>ICI4 4200</th>
                <th>ICI5 3400</th>
                <th>RB</th>
                <th>DES ARA </th>
                <th>HBA</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            
           
            <tbody>
             <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}> 
            {datas.map((x)=>(
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name='hba_date' value={x.hba_date} disabled  {...register("hba_date")}/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name='hba_day' value={x.hba_day} disabled/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name='platts_K5900' value={x.platts_K5900}/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name='GCNEWC_6322' value={x.GCNEWC_6322}/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name='NEX' value={x.NEX}/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name='ICI1_6500' value={x.ICI1_6500}/></td>
                {x.hba_day ==='Friday' ? (
                <td><input type="text" name='weekly_ICI2_5800' value={x.weekly_ICI2_5800} /></td>
                ):(
                    <td><input type="text"  name='weekly_ICI2_5800' value={x.weekly_ICI2_5800} disabled/></td> 
                )}
                {x.hba_day ==='Friday' ? (
                <td><input type="text"  name='weekly_ICI3_5000' value={x.weekly_ICI3_5000}/></td>
                ):(
                    <td><input type="text" name='weekly_ICI3_5000' value={x.weekly_ICI3_5000} disabled/></td>
                )}
                 {x.hba_day ==='Friday' ? (
                <td><input type="text" name='weekly_ICI4_4200' value={x.weekly_ICI4_4200}/></td>
                ):(
                    <td><input type="text"  name='weekly_ICI4_4200'  value={x.weekly_ICI4_4200} disabled/></td>
                )}
                
                {x.hba_day ==='Friday' ? (
                <td><input type="text"  name='weekly_ICI5_3400' value={x.weekly_ICI5_3400}/></td>
                ):(
                    <td><input type="text" name='weekly_ICI5_3400' value={x.weekly_ICI5_3400} disabled/></td>
                )}
                  {x.hba_day ==='Friday' ? (
                <td><input type="text" name='weekly_RB' value={x.weekly_RB}/></td>
                ):(
                    <td><input type="text" name="weekly_RB" value={x.weekly_RB} disabled/></td>
                )}
                    {x.hba_day ==='Friday' ? (
                <td><input type="text" name="weekly_DES_ARA" value={x.weekly_DES_ARA}/></td>
                ):(
                    <td><input type="text"  name='weekly_DES_ARA' value={x.weekly_DES_ARA} disabled/></td>
                )}
                
                {x.hba_day ==='Friday' ? (
                <td><input type="text" name="month_HBA" value={x.month_HBA}/></td>
                ):(
                    <td><input type="text" name="month_HBA" value={x.month_HBA} disabled/></td>
                )}
                 
                <td><input type="text" name="hba_status" value={x.hba_status}/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="hba_remarks" value={x.hba_remarks}/></td>
                
            
            </tr>
            ))}
            <input type="submit"  className="addaccount-save" value='Save'/>
            </form> 
           </tbody>
           
        </table>
        
        <p className="edit-btn">
                  <button className="btn btn-primary">
                    Save
                  </button>
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                     
                  >
                    Cancel
                  </button>
                </p>
    </Form>
    <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HBA;
```

Comment: Could you please help me any genius

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the updated code :

```
function HBA() {
  
  const body=$(window).height()
  const header=$("#header").height()
  const nav=$(".navbar").height()
  const footer=$(".footer").height()
  const total_height=header+nav+footer;
  const window_height=body-total_height;
  console.log(total_height)
  console.log(body)
    const location=useLocation();
  const {pricebookName}=location.state;
  console.log(pricebookName)
   
  const location = useLocation();
  const { pricebookName } = location.state;

  const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [decryptedAccessToken]);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`https://rwood.znapay.in:5000/get/all_hba/${pricebookName}`, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedAccessToken}` },
      });
      const data = response.data.records;
      setDatas(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = [];
    datas.forEach((x) => {
      const formItem = {
        hba_date: x.hba_date,
        hba_day: x.hba_day,
        platts_K5900: e.target[`platts_K5900_${x.id}`].value,
        // Add other form fields here....
      };
      formData.push(formItem);
    });

    try {
      const response = await axios.post('YOUR_ENDPOINT_URL_HERE', formData, {
        headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${decryptedAccessToken}` },
      });

      console.log(response.data);
      toast.success('Data submitted successfully!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      toast.error('Error submitting data');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="addAccount">
      {/* Your header component */}

      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <table className="table table-bordered hba">
          {/* Your table headers */}
          <tbody>
            {datas.map((x) => (
              <tr key={x.id}>
                {/* Your table data.......... */}
                <td>
                  <input type="text" name={`platts_K5900_${x.id}`} defaultValue={x.platts_K5900} />
                </td>
                {/* Add other input fields......... */}
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <p className="edit-btn">
          <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
            Save
          </button>
          {/* Add cancel button */}
        </p>
      </Form>

      {/* Your footer component */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default HBA;
```